# adding --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED to a java 17 application running on gradle

Tags: gradle, jar, build.gradle, java-17

i need help in adding this
`--add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED`
to a java 17 application running on gradle
what is the elegant way of doing this?
and how do we verify if it is being picked up?

Comment: Why do you think you need this option? If you can answer this question, you can also answer the question how to verify its effect.